# Is it possible to create an insecure RFCOMM socket between Android and Google Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a Bluetooth application where a smartphone (the client) connects to a web browser  of another computer (the server). When triggered by a user action on the client, data will be sent to the web browser over the Bluetooth channel. Prior security association is not necessary, and the address of the server will be communicated out of band to the client in advance. Therefore I want to skip the pairing and discovery phase completely.

The Android Bluetooth stack allows for the above by creating an insecure RFCOMM connection for clients `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` method, and correspondingly `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord`.

It is not clear whether the Chrome Bluetooth Stack offers the same services according to the [Bluetooth Javascript API](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/bluetooth.html). From what I can tell, there is no way to use `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord`, and their examples only show the web browser used as a client. I would like to confirm if this is a possibility with the current state of Google Chrome, or a some other way to enable this type of communication.

There have been many questions previously asked about making insecure pairings with Android devices but none with other Bluetooth enabled devices/applications (such as a web browser in this case). None of the previous responses seemed to address the scenario which I describe.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to this Google article: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web?hl=en And also you can follow the Web bluetooth community group: https://www.w3.org/community/web-bluetooth/

This is possible to search for a device and create a socket communication with web bluetooth.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Android implements Bluetooth 4.0, as does Chrome OS, Windows and OS X, and insecure connections are not permitted in that version of the specification.

When the two devices connect, they will both indicate to each other that they support Secure Simple Pairing (SSP) and thus the specification requires that they begin negotiation for Encryption, even if a temporary key is used.

Thus the connection is not "insecure"

Comment: Can you please provide more details from where you know that it's impossible? This is actually a very interesting question. What about to create the client with a chrome extension supporting Chrome bluetooth API and inject it into an Android device? It may be possible to make it work this way.